# Subclassing list: am I doing it properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass

I want to subclass `list` into `Clause` to give it three properties:

1. Every element of a `Clause` is a `Lit`
2. Certain operators like `|` and `&` are overloaded
3. If `a` and `b` are of type `Clause`, then so is `a+b`

This is what I've got so far, but I'm pretty sure it's wrong... what's the best way to do this?

```
class Clause(list):
    def __init__(self, raw_list):
        for lit in raw_list:
            if not isinstance(lit, Lit):
                raise TypeError, 'Clause contains non-Lit elements'
        self = raw_list

    def __invert__(self):
        return Formula([Clause([~lit]) for lit in self])

    def __or__(self, right):
        if not isinstance(right, Clause):
            raise TypeError, 'RHS is not of type Clause'
        return Formula([self + right])

    def __and__(self, right):
        if not isinstance(right, Clause):
            raise TypeError, 'RHS is not of type Clause'
        return Formula([self, right])
```

Comment: 1. `for lit in list`?? 2. `self = raw_list` is useless. Have you tested your code?

Comment: At a glance, there are some obvious bugs:  (1) `for lit in list:` makes no sense - `list` is a type, not a variable.  (2) `self = raw_list` at the end of `__init__` makes no sense.  It's a local assignment that has no effect.

Comment: (1) sorry, typo, fixed (2) ya, I know it's wrong, I'm wondering what the right way is

Answer (score 0):

The statement self = raw_list does nothing.

You should call list constructor instead :

```
list.__init__(self, raw_list)
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use super?

Comment: Maybe, but then it should be used everywhere. In all the code I write (ie, smallish GUI or tools), I've found it more readable to call directly the __init__ methods of parent classes than to use super. That said, the choice is yours. :)